# Artifacts eevee viewport, cycles is fine

Tags: eevee-render-engine, artifacts

I can't figure out why I get artifacts in the viewport with material and Eevee render views. Cycles is fine — the same issue across Blender versions 3.3.7, 3.5, and 3.5.1. I have an i9 and 5700xt on Mac OS 12.6.1. I have swapped the GPU backend setting to OpenGL and Metal without any change. The attached image shows the default cube and an open/hollow cube with texture in the background. Any suggestions are greatly appreciated. - Rob

[image: viewport display: top, material - middle, eevvee render - bottom, cycles render]